rmarkdown figure does not appear on pdf
I create a set of slides using rmarkdown. I add a figure using latex includegraphics which works as expected. But, when I add a figure generate via R code, the 'latex' figure disappears.
Minimal code example
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "JS"
subtitle: SUBTITLE
output:
  beamer_presentation: 
    keep_tex: yes
  ioslides_presentation: default
fontsize: 14pt
---



# Example 

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{include_figure}
\end{figure}

---

# Add figure via R code

```{r, message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE, eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE}
plot(rnorm(100))

Any suggestions what I do wrong?

The closing code fence of the r code is missing. Beamer also doesn't have a floating mechanism, you don't need [t]. Beamer centres figures by default, you don't have to centre them again.

sure. Though if I remove [t], add closing fence, and \centering the problem remains.

Update:
This bug has been fixed in pandoc v3.2.1. The workaround below should no longer be necessary

For some reason rmarkdown and/or pandoc thinks that adding
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}

to the preamble would be a good idea... which it is evidently not.
You can avoid the problem by specifying the height of the image instead of a scaling factor:
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "JS"
subtitle: SUBTITLE
output:
  beamer_presentation: 
    keep_tex: yes
  ioslides_presentation: default
fontsize: 14pt
---



# Example 

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}

---

# Add figure via R code

```{r, message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE, eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE}
plot(rnorm(100))
```


@JonasStriaukas You're welcome! (and you might want to ask rmarkdown or pandoc or whoever else inserts this code to stop doing that)
